# Exporting data from c# to word document

Tags: c#, asp.net, grid, export-to-word

I have a grid in c# filled with data. One of the columns in that grid contains letters (followed by numbers) sorted alphabetically, like this:

```
A124
A256
A756
B463
B978
D322
etc.
```

I need to export this data in a word document (.doc or .docx format).
This is what i did to export a signle grid:

```
var dt = FuntionThatReturnsDatatables();

var gd = new GridView
        {
            DataSource = dt                     
        };

        gd.DataBind();

        HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Buffer = true;

        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;
        filename=" + "List" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy") + ".doc");

        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/ms-word";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Charset = "UTF-8";

      HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetPreamble()); 

        var oStringWriter = new StringWriter();
        var oHtmlTextWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(oStringWriter);

        gd.RenderControl(oHtmlTextWriter);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Output.Write(oStringWriter.ToString());
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```

But now I have to follow this logic:
 - For every letter from grid a new table with title should be created like this:

```
Table A:
 A124
 A256
 A756
```

[image]

[image]

- Each new table should start from a new page, like this:

  Table A:
      A124,
      A256,
      A756,
      //new page

  Table B:
  B463,
  B978,
  //new page

  Table D:
  D322,
  etc.
- Pages in that word document need to be numbered.

Is there any way to write a code in c# to do this or is there some library/plugin that can accomplish this task ?

Some examples would be appreciated.

Comment: If you're able and/or allowed to spend money on a library, you might have a look at Aspose.Words to write Word Documents: http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.words-for-.net/default.aspx

Comment: You are not creating a word document at all. Your code creates an HTML document and forces the client to open it using Word.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to use OpenXML SDK from Microsoft to achieve this.

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb448854.aspx

Reference Sample:

1. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/acoat/archive/2010/06/19/document-creation-and-conversion-with-the-openxml-sdk-and-sharepoint-2010-word-automation-services.aspx
2. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/acoat/archive/2011/04/06/document-creation-and-conversion-with-the-openxml-sdk-and-sharepoint-2010-word-automation-services-part-2.aspx

Answer (score 0):

What version of Word do you need to work with? If it's a version that can handle the .docx file format, i.e. 2007 and later, then you can generate those files directly. In fact, the easiest way to do that is create a .docx file in Word that you use as a kind of template, and then programmatically manipulate the xml in that file.

For more information, see

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163526.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.packaging.aspx