# C# - HttpContext error when trying to save HTML to Word in C#

Tags: c#, html, ms-word

I am writing a plugin in c#. And I have an html in a `Stringwriter` and I am trying to output it as a Word document based on other samples I have researched on SO and other places on the web. Such as this: [Exporting data from c# to word document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10913985/exporting-data-from-c-sharp-to-word-document) and http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/196851/export-an-html-to-word-document-with-fixed-headers

For the life of me I cannot figure out why I get a NullReference exception on the first line `HttpContext` appears (actually how to handle it is what I am stuck on).

Here is the code:

```cs
using System.Web;

HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
HttpContext.Current.Response.Buffer = true;
HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application//ms-word";
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", @"attachment; filename=D:\WORK_ORDER.doc");
HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF32;
HttpContext.Current.Response.Charset = "UTF-16";
// HttpContext.Current.EnableViewState = false;
HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetPreamble());
HttpContext.Current.Response.Output.Write(swSource.ToString());
HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```

I am sure it is too simple. Can somebody point out what I am missing here? Thanks.

**Update**: I had posted the stack trace, but it is non-informative an lengthy. The additional information is more telling:

> Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

All the similar examples show only this code, no instantiation, so I am at loss how to do this, so I'd appreciate some advice.

**Update:**

According to the approved answer all that happened, that importing the reference library `System.Web` does not mean that you can use this `HttpContext` object in a non-web app.

See my solution posted below as an answer.

Comment: Where exactly do you get the NullReferenceException?

Comment: Like Manfred asked, could you please show the stacktrace?

Comment: Where does `swSource` come from?

Comment: Side notes: HTML is not DOC... and UTF32/UTF16/UTF8 are not the same thing...

Comment: The NullReference Exception is on the first line: `HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();`

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Thanks. I figured it out. Word opens the html if saved with a DOC extension with the above header, see updated code. And the UTF16 vs UTF8 came about that my HTML is encoded in UTF16.

Comment: @ib11 please *do not* update question with answer. You can post solution you've come up with as answer instead.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov -- Ah okay. I saw this a lot in other posts. Why is that a problem though?

Comment: @ib11 on SO question is for single concrete question, answers are for answers to that question. If anyone else comes to that question they would expect question to describe problem and answers to provide solution. Mixing question and answer into single post produce confusing experience. If you see other questions including answer - feel free to comment or maybe flag for moderator attention (with explanation that "question includes answer" - usually it such edit will be simply rolled back).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov OK, thanks for clarifying an makes sense. Fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were to guess I'd say your project is a class library or some non web application project.

If this is the case you will not have access to httpcontext and you'll either have to change your project to a web project or you can look at alternative methods of saving your file. For example:
[Writing Text File to Folder on Desktop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22205767/writing-text-file-to-folder-on-desktop)

*note I've not tried the suggested solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think that this just solves the issue. I am writing basically a UserContol, not web app. Just nowhere it says that I cannot use this object in a non web app project.

Comment: No problem. However in a roundabout way it is saying you can't use it by means of a null reference exception. Httpcontext should never be null if it's a valid usage scenario.

Answer (score 0):

As per Lee's answer the solution was not to use `HttpContext` at all.

Instead write this Word doc to file directly (and it WORKS perfectly), by replacing the above snippet to this code:

```
StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder();
StringWriter swSource = new StringWriter(sb1);

//load swSource here with an HTML through an XSL Transformation

sb1.Replace("<html>","<html xmlns:o='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office'" +
"xmlns:w='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40'>" +
"<head><title>Time</title>"+
"<!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><w:WordDocument>"+
"<w:View>Print</w:View><w:Zoom>100</w:Zoom>"+
"<w:DoNotOptimizeForBrowser/></w:WordDocument></xml><![endif]-->");

System.IO.StreamWriter writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"D:\Test.doc", false, Encoding.Unicode); //open the file for writing.               
writer.Write(sb1.ToString()); //write the current date to the file. change this with your date or something.
writer.Close();
```

I posted this here so the data is available if there are others like me believing they can use `HttpContext` just by referencing the `System.Web` library.